# How can I restart while loop after certain condition (if) satisfied in c++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I have a lot of if statements in while loop, program has to print error messages according to conditions, but if there are more than one error it has to be only one of them.

Comment: maybe a `switch case` statement can work better

Comment: Do you mean go to the next iteration of the loop, or restart the loop as if from the first iteration?

Comment: but after conditions, i have to read next part of the string(command) in order to know if there is an error for them or not? and all of them has to be in while loop because user keeps going to type commands

Comment: yes Jerry Coffin, that is exactly what i wanted to say

Comment: You should Prefer Switch rather than multiple If or if-else ladder ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question isn't very detailed so it's a little hard to tell what exactly do you want.

If you want the while loop to go to the next iteration after any error has fired, you should use the `continue` statement:

```
while( something )
{
    if( condition )
    {
        //do stuff
        continue;
    }
    else if( condition 2 )
    {
        //do other stuff
        continue;
    }
    <...>
}
```

If nothing else than these `if`s is inside the loop, and the conditions are integer values, you should consider using `switch` instead:

```
while( condition )
{
    switch( errorCode )
    {
        case 1:
        //do stuff;
        break;
        case 2:
        //do other stuff;
        break;
        <...>
    }
}
```

If you want to completely restart the cycle... well this is a little harder. Since you have a `while` loop, you can just set the condition to it's starting value. For example, if you have a loop like this:

```
int i = 0;
while( i < something )
{
    //do your stuff
    i++;
}
```

then you can "reset" it like this:

```
int i = 0;
while( i < something )
{
    //do your stuff
    if( something that tells you to restart the loop )
    {
        i = 0;//setting the conditional variable to the starting value
        continue;//and going to the next iteration to "restart" the loop
    }
}
```

However, you should be really careful with this, it's easy to get an infinite loop accidentally.

Comment: it is not about all integer, command includes string, integer, double. According to priority of the error, only one error has to be appeared on terminal. but mine is like puts every error on terminal

Comment: @user, then just use `else if`s with a `continue` statement in each to go to the next iteration after any error is put.

Comment: In the first code, no need of _continue_ statement

Comment: @Sha, I was waiting for this comment. We don't know if there is any other code after a number of `if` statements. If there is no - you are right. If there is - the `continue` is needed.

Comment: You are right. I also thought so. But he didn't write any code. So we didn't know.

Answer (score -2):

```
String errorMessage = "No Error";

while( cond){
if( cond 1) {
  errorMessage = " Error 1"
}

if( cond 1) {
  errorMessage = " Error 1"
}

if( cond 1) {
  errorMessage = " Error 1"
}

if( cond 1) {
  errorMessage = " Error 1"
}
}
```

If you want to break after any error that is encountered, use `break`

If you want to ignore the current iteration after any error is encountered , use `continue`

If you want to terminate the execution after any error is encountered, use `exit`

Comment: Hm, I believe this is what the OP needs to get rid off actually.